# How to render fields based on picklist value?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a requirement to render input fields based on the user selected value in `Select option`,please give me any ideas or suggestions how to achieve this, I am using JSP pages?

```
<select name="Bank" id=Bank">
   <option>Choose Bank</option>
   <option value="hdfc">HDFC</option>
   <option value="other">OTHER</option>   
</select>

<div id="other" class="selectBankType" style="display:none;">
<input type="text" name="accountNumber"/>
<input type="text" name="IFSC"/>
</div>

<div id="hdfc" class="selectBankType" style="display:none;">
<input type="text" name="accountNumber"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the `jquery` for this , In your select tag use an function like `onChange="toggleSubmit('d',this)"`

And using jquery render the input fields [**append**](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function,

```
$('#myDiv').append('<input type="text" name="' + name + '" />');
```

**Update:**

This could be easily done with `change` event and jquery hide/show () function as

```
 $(function() {
        $('#Bank').change(function(){
            $('.selectBankType').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
```

see this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rsEY8/)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply i updated my question what i want is when select same bank i just want to show only account number field,when i select other i need to show both account number and IFSC code field,can you please provide me a sample code

Comment: @user3168055 i have updated my code . check it through comment here if you need any help